# Creating a Curve Tool using Java2D and Swing for my Java Vector Graphics Editor

Tags: java, swing, graphics, vector, java-2d

I am creating a Vector Graphics editor and have successfully created the paint-brush and some basic 2d shapes like Rectange,  Ellipse , Line etc. Now what's bothering me is the Curved Line or Curve tool. I created the others by getting the original point from *mousePressed* and then updating the second point on each *mouseDragged*. Here's part of the code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    gfx.setColor(Tool.currentColor);
    pos1 = e.getPoint(); //Get the First Point
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    if(!e.isAltDown() && !e.isMetaDown())

    if(currentShape != null) shapeSet.add(currentShape);
    currentShape = null;
}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.isAltDown() || e.isMetaDown()) return;
    //the mouse was dragged, so begin painting
    pos2 = e.getPoint();

    int ctool = Tool.currentTool;

    if(ctool == Tool.LINE){
        currentShape = new Line(pos1,pos2,Tool.currentColor,null);
    }else if(ctool == Tool.ELLIPSE){
        currentShape = new Ellipse(pos1,pos2,Tool.currentColor,null);
    }else if(ctool == Tool.RECTANGLE){
        currentShape = new Rectangle(pos1,pos2,Tool.currentColor,null);
    }

    this.repaint();
}
```

The Line,Ellipse etc. classes are quite simple, they just take the points and draw them later in the repaint. All the Shapes temporarily stored in *currentShape* are then later appended to shapeSet , which is an ArrayList of the abstract class *Shape*.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    gfx.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    gfx.clearRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    for(int i=0; i< shapeSet.size(); i++){
        shapeSet.get(i).draw(gfx);
    }
    if(currentShape != null){
        currentShape.draw(gfx);
    }

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

img is a **BufferedImage** and gfx is img's **Graphics**.

```
img = new BufferedImage(640,480,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
gfx = img.createGraphics(); //Graphics2D
```

Now how exactly would I go about creating a **Curve Tool**?

**P.S** If you want the code of the Shape (Line,Ellipse etc.) classes, just comment and I'll post it.

Comment: I have edited my question and mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [*Bézier Curve Editor in Java*](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~mlh/codebase/grafisk2/) that might give you some ideas, but I'm not sure how you'd integrate it into your program.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html

You have to define SEG_QUADTO or SEG_CUBICTO. Just add a new segment with propr double coordinates.

Comment: ouch, an old link - @Andrew Thompson will be not amused :-)